# what will be the Authorization schemes for new user? in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

```
FUNCTION my_auth (
    p_username IN varchar2,
    p_password IN varchar2)
RETURN BOOLEAN AS
    found number := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO FOUND FROM users
            WHERE upper(email)=upper(p_username)
            AND upper(password)=upper(p_password)
            AND is_activated=1;
RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

/* I have now three users 'admin','guest','other'
and the have following authorization administration,view only,edit. 
if another user signs up in application what will be his/her authorization.
i want he will be allotted edit privilege automatically. all the new user will get the edit privileges. how can i do it?*/

Answer (score 0):

You can create various authorization schemes according to functional need.
For eg. You can create different authorization schemes such as for create,update,delete,readonly etc.

```
FUNCTION create_auth (p_username IN varchar2,
                      p_password IN varchar2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN AS
  found number := 0;
BEGIN
     SELECT 1 INTO FOUND FROM users
      WHERE upper(email)=upper(p_username)
        AND upper(password)=upper(p_password)
        AND is_activated=1
        AND ROLE='create';
     RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

Above functions return true/false based on role exist to user.
Similarly you can create edit_auth(authorization) and user role can be  edit/update then that authorization you can apply to editable component of page.
For more information about authorization please check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/sec_authorization.htm#HTMDB25783

Hope this will help you!